# Data recovery options for unix file systems

Tags: linux, bsd

What popular and tried data recovery options are there?

I know of these (none of which have GUIs afaik):

- foremost - Forensics application to recover data
- scalpel - A Frugal, High Performance File Carver
- ext3grep - Tool to help recover deleted files on ext3 filesystems
- e2undel - Undelete utility for the ext2 file system

Do you know of any that have desktop frontends? It's a tool you don't get to use much, reading manuals and searching for correct flags is not efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had excellent results with [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk). No gui, but the next best thing ... console menus! [And an excellent wiki for use cases.](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk#Documentation)

Many an accidentally deleted thumbdrive has been rescued.

Comment: +1 for mentioning a program I almost forgot about! Thanks for remembering me!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll find GUI frontends for these. Ext3grep is your best option for recovering files though: I used it for the first time a couple of weeks ago and was easily[1] able to recover all the pictures I had deleted.

Compared to a couple of years back, ext3grep has made life a lot easier. It takes some time, but it does the job and does it pretty well.

[1] Easily is relative to what it used to be, before ext3grep.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly for Unix file systems (it does not depend on file systems at all) but I can recommend [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec). You'll probably find it in testdisk package